# Using chunked upload/StartUpload with sharepoint REST api

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, file-upload, office365apis

I want to upload large files to SharePoint Online but I am unable to use chunked upload of sharepoint REST API. I would like to see a working example.

The api is described in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileStartUpload) using the methods

```
startUpload(GUID, stream1) continueUpload(GUID, 10 MB, stream2)
continueUpload(GUID, 20 MB, stream3)
finishUpload(GUID, 30 MB, stream4)
```

I found the same question in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5596f87a-3155-4e4f-a6e8-8d38fa5e580d/office-365-onedrive-for-businesssharepoint-rest-api-startupload-command?forum=appsforsharepoint

but the solution uses C# and I need REST.

Answer (score 4):

The following C# sample shows how to upload large file using the [`StartUpload`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bk_FileStartUpload), [`ContinueUpload`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileContinueUpload), and [`FinishUpload`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn450841.aspx#bk_FileFinishUpload) REST endpoints:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = webUri;
    client.Credentials = GetCredentials(webUri, userName, password);
    client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    client.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", RequestFormDigest());

    var fileUrl = "/Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx";
    var endpointUrlS = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/savebinarystream", webUri, fileUrl);
    var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

    var firstChunk = true;
    var uploadId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var offset = 0L;
    const int chunkSize = 2048; //<-set chunk size (bytes)
    using (var inputStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
         var buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
         int bytesRead;
         while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
         {
              if (firstChunk)
              {
                  var endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/startupload(uploadId=guid'{2}')", webUri, fileUrl,uploadId);
                  client.UploadData(endpointUrl, buffer);
                  firstChunk = false;                           
              }
              else if (inputStream.Position == inputStream.Length)
              {
                  var endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/finishupload(uploadId=guid'{2}',fileOffset={3})", webUri, fileUrl, uploadId,offset);
                  var finalBuffer = new byte[bytesRead];
                  Array.Copy(buffer , finalBuffer , finalBuffer.Length);
                  client.UploadData(endpointUrl, finalBuffer);
              }
              else
              {
                  var endpointUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/continueupload(uploadId=guid'{2}',fileOffset={3})", webUri, fileUrl, uploadId, offset);
                  client.UploadData(endpointUrl, buffer);
              }
              offset += bytesRead;
              Console.WriteLine("%{0:P} completed", (((float)offset / (float)inputStream.Length) ));
          }
      }
 }
```

> - For consuming SharePoint REST Interface [`WebClient class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) is    utilized, in particular `UploadData Method` for uploading data.
> - [GetCredentials.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/30391ddac67c6e6b7516) - method for getting SharePoint Online credentials
> - SharePoint REST `POST` requests requires form digest to be specified, `RequestFormDigest` is intended for that purpose (you could find the
>     implementation of it [here](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/41872624b010f3f5c730))

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I've tried this and I get the following error: /personal/tenant_awbrazier_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/largefile.zip does not exist. when it goes to do the first chunk. If I upload a file with the same name it then works

Comment: I am looking same solution for REST API because I am using SharePoint online

Comment: I am also getting that error when uploading the first chunk