# The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 262144000 bytes

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, onedrive-for-business

I've been getting the following error message recently when uploading a file using the REST API:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException - The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 262144000 bytes.

I've been using this method to upload files both small and large to SharePoint for a while now and never come across this error before. I've been looking at some articles and it appears this message could appear when uploading a file using CSOM. In this case I am not, I do you use csom to add permissions and perform some other small updates.

This is the code used for the REST call:
http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/uploading-large-documents-into.html (Uploading Large Documents With REST)

Comment: Can you update your post to include your REST API call?

Comment: @mcgeeky added a link

Comment: any upload limit change on the Web app level?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE not that I know of, is there a way I can check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft introduced a new large file upload API to upload files up to 10GB in size. See [Using chunked upload/StartUpload with sharepoint REST api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161845/using-chunked-upload-startupload-with-sharepoint-rest-api) for an example.

Perhaps they have implemented a new restriction on the approach you have been using now that the new large file upload API has been rolled out?

Either way, you should find the new large file upload API more reliable so I recommend you switch to using this approach.

Comment: I've been going through my traces and it looks like they may have put a limit in place now